# converting Ganeti instance to vmdk fails

Tags: ovf, ganeti, vmdk

I have exported an instance from ganeti using this command :

```
gnt-backup export -n
```

I get these files:

```
/srv/ganeti/export/win2k8.itlao.local# ls
6dac4bb5-19e9-4917-8233-39cecfbe0e39.disk0_data.snap  config.ini
```

When I try to convert for VMWARE using this :

```
./ovfconverter export --external --format=vmdk --output-dir ~/ganeti-instance/   /srv/ganeti/export/win2k8.itlao.local/config.ini
2014-03-19 13:17:33,870: ('No memory information found', 'environment_error')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./ovfconverter", line 181, in main
    converter.Parse()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ganeti/ovf.py", line 1759, in Parse
    self.results_memory = self._ParseMemory()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ganeti/ovf.py", line 1613, in _ParseMemory
    errors.ECODE_ENVIRON)
OpPrereqError: ('No memory information found', 'environment_error')
```

Are my commands correct? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What version of Ganeti?

Answer (score 1):

You should add memory= with the same value as maxmem in the backend section of your config.ini file.